# Seeding pseudo random generator with random number from a better random source

Tags: c++, c, security, random, entropy

Let's say we have a pseudo random number generator that accepts a 32 bit integer as seed (for example the `rand()` function from the C standard library), which derives random numbers from the original seed. If that seed were to come from, let's say, radioactive decay, is it correct to assume that the random number we get from calling `rand()` is as "good" random number as taking generating one from radioactive decay?

Comment: Are you asking if seeding from decay is better than seeding from, say, ticks since program start?

Comment: Look into [these facilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

Comment: The first number is good, when the random number generator does not remove entropy (e.g. when the seed is 32 bit, the generator should be able to output all possible 2^32 values (instead of e..g only 2^16 ones by throwing away to upper 16 bits)).  But quality of subsequently generated numbers will decrease more and more unless seed is refilled with entropy.

Comment: @ensc That's exactly what I assumed! cool! But what about deriving a bigger number from this seed? I.E 64 bit from a 32 bit seed?

Comment: @UnTraDe The new number will not contain more than 32 bit of entropy.

Comment: A good random number generator is like a well shuffled deck of card. The seed determines how you cut the deck. No cut is better than another.

Comment: @user515430 Except that a true random sequence have repeating numbers.

Comment: @plasmacel - But that's not sufficient to answer the question.  With a truly random seed, the entire sequence is now random.  However, the individual elements are still predictable *if the seed is known*.  So some extra constraints are required in order to define "good".

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth No, even if you use a truly random number to seed a pseudo random number generator, that doesn't mean that the entire sequence is random at all. The seed has nothing to do with randomness. Read my answer for more details.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth You can easily define a really bad random number generator as `x = x + 1`. Then try to seed it with a truly random number. According to you, the "entire sequence is now random". Actually, since the initial seed is truly random, there is no way to predict which will be the first number of your pseudorandom sequence, but then it will be as bad as it is: the sequence won't be random at all.

Comment: @plasmacel - each item **will** be random (if `x` is a random variable, then `x + 1` is still a random variable), but they'll all be correlated (in the colloquial sense). But that's my point - defining "good" as "truly random" is not particularly helpful when it comes to RNGs.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I think your definition of randomness is flawed. The quality of randomness is rather a statistical property. It is some kind of the absence of measurable correlation. Even less correlated, even more random, and vice-versa. In that sense I would argue that `x + 1` is random. Even by simple observation of the samples you are able to predict the next one. I would be surprised if it would pass any of the Diehard or TestU01 tests. You are right however, that defining good as truly random is not a good idea at the case of PRNGs, but that is just what the OP asked.

Comment: That won’t save you from patterns in the output that might let someone who sees the pseudo-random values guess the next one.

Comment: @plasmacel - Going way off on a tangent now (!), but check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Functions_of_random_variables

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I think there is a confusion about the terminology. In measure theoretic terms, the "random variable" is actually a Borel measurable function. Well, this means that by definition, even `x = 1` is a "random variable", even if it's actually not random, but a constant value. It even has a probability distribution function (PDF) `f(x) = dirac(x-1)`, where `dirac` is the Dirac delta function. Its PDF nicely integrates to 1. But this is a degenerate "random variable", so the term "random variable" doesn't automatically mean that it is random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, definitely not.** The C/C++ standard library's builtin `rand()` function is usually implemented as a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) (LCG). It is among the earliest known family of pseudorandom number generators (PRNGs) and they generally have notoriously bad statistical properties. Furthermore since PRNGs actually produce a mathematical sequence predetermined by an initial seed, they are predictable. Even cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generators (like the [Blum Blum Shub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_Blum_Shub)) are predictable, even if it's computationally difficult and very time consuming to predict the sequence.

In contrast, random number generators based on radioactive decay are true random number generators. The generated sequence of numbers is perfectly uniformly distributed and unpredictable, without any measurable correlation between the samples.

Back to pseudorandom numbers, the statistical quality of the source of the initial seed doesn't improve the statistical quality of the generated pseudorandom sequence - it only depends on the generator itself. If you use a true random number to seed a PRNG, then the first number of the sequence will be unpredictable, but then the quality of the sequence will be the same as it would be without the true random seed.

If you want high quality of randomness, you have to use a high quality random number generator. There are pseudorandom number generators with excellent statistical properties (definitely **not** the famous [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister)), passing all current statistical tests of randomness - while the generated pseudorandom sequence is still predictable, statistically it's hard to distinguish from a truly random sequence.

A good reliable resource on modern random number generators is [Sebastiano Vigna's website](http://xoroshiro.di.unimi.it).

Answer (score 1):

The quality of your random numbers comes from the quality of your random number generator.  There are many and varied methods of generating pseudo random numbers, the one you choose should be suitable for your application, but to be honest, if you have access to radio active decay monitoring equipment, then you are probably able to access real random numbers (from some other totally random real world event), rather than seeding a pseudo one.

Comment: But the random seed sure affects the results no matter what is the algorithm right? Let's say the pseudo algorithm is "s+n+1", where *s* is the seed, *n* is the index of the number you want to generate and *1* is a constant. You seed this algorithm with the number 896, generated from monitoring radioactive decay, then the first number outputted by the algorithm is 897, which is as hard/impossible to guess as the seed number. Subsequent numbers generated with this algorithm without reseeding it will be very easy to predict, but the first one isn`t?

Comment: As long as you always seed with a different (random) number, then the source is irrelevant.   As long as there is human interaction, there will be variability, so I doubt using a decay method to generate the seed is any better than how long it took for someone to click on a UI to start a program.  Of course, it this were a server that always rebooted at midnight, and you took the ticks since the start of the day as your seed , it will not be a good method.

Comment: @UnTraDe Your assumptions are right in your comment. If your initial seed is truly random, there is no way to predict the first number of the sequence (since the 1st number only depends on that truly random number, without any previous state). The quality of the subsequent numbers however determined by the pseudorandom number generator.

Answer (score 1):

**NO**. The properties of the random number **sequence** depends entirely on the random number generator (RNG). Thus, any correlation between subsequent random numbers are down to the RNG and not to the seed.

However, having said that, the seed is important to avoid similarities between the sequences generated at different runs of your code. So, you should always attempt to seed your RNG with genuinely random seeds.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudorandom numbers(PRN) may be a sequence of *near random numbers*. However, the True random numbers (TRN) are the ones that generate random numbers by taking inputs from *entropy sources* which can be any kind of physical environment right from vibration to harddisk activity. The rand() of C library belongs to the category of PRN. For high randomness, it is better to go with libraries that use /dev/random or /dev/urandom.

Refer to manpage of urandom as well for more details on random, urandom - kernel random number source devices at https://linux.die.net/man/4/urandom. 
*" The random number generator gathers environmental noise from device drivers and other sources into an entropy pool. The generator also keeps an estimate of the number of bits of noise in the entropy pool. From this entropy pool random numbers are created. "*